# Avoid publish of EJBs and ManagedBeans when saving xhtml file in Maven project

Tags: eclipse, maven, jsf-2, glassfish-3

I have setup a two eclipse projects (jsf2 web projects) and deployed them via eclipse to glassfish

```
eclipse juno ee 4.2.1 sr1 (fresh install and new workspace)
maven wtp
m2e
glassfish plugin for eclipse
glassfish 3.1.2.2
```

One project is a simple dynamic web project created from scratch that only has an ejb and a .xhtml file.

When saving the .xhtml file in the dynamic web project, it will be silently copied to the right place in glassfish/domains/domain1/eclipseApps allowing to quickly test changes.

However in my other project which I created by using the import-maven-project-wizard (select a .pom file), saving a .xhtml file will trigger a rebuild and republish, something which takes considerably more time. In both cases the application runs perfectly fine.

(The maven project is also more complex using primefaces, some glassfish-web.xml persistence.xml etc... But i believe this is not causing the different behaviour)

Q: What setting do I need to change to have my maven project behave as the dynamic web-project?

Edit:
problem summary: Saving a .xhtml file in the maven project also trigers re-deploy of all EJBs and ManagedBeans

Edit (after balus C's tip):

Investigation indicates that m2e wtp plugin generates new timestamp in the following files, every time a file in the workspace is saved.

```
target\m2e-wtp\web-resources\META-INF\maven\<groupId>\<artifactId>\pom.properties
target\m2e-wtp\web-resources\META-INF\maven\<groupId>\<artifactId>\pom.xml
```

If I understand the discussion [here](https://github.com/sonatype/m2eclipse-extras/issues/8) correctly, someone has done a fix that will prevent these files from being updated if not required due to other maven stuff. Sadly if I understand the git-hub correctly, this fix for this issue is not yet released.

[Maven archiver](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/) has support for a configuration option `<addMavenDescriptor/>` to disable the generation of pom.properties, but it seems m2e-wtp plugin has decided to not honor this option [link](https://github.com/sonatype/m2eclipse-extras/issues/9)

Edit (20130114)
I Tried uninstalling m2e wtp just to see if geting rid of the generation of pom.properties would fix the problem. Also I checked that the .xhtml file I edit is the only file under domains/domain1/eclipseApps/ with new timestamp.

So now im out of ideas again.

Comment: I don't do Maven, but have you turned off publishing in server configuration? Doubleclick server entry in *servers* view, under the section *Publishing* select "Never publish automatically"? That does it for non-Maven projects.

Comment: I have the same server setup for both projects, if i change it to Never publish automaticly, the .xhtml files are no longer silently copied to eclipseApps when I save them.

Comment: I suppose you have the *build automatically* option of your Eclipse turned off. You should also turn auto-validation of your xml-xhtml files off. In fact doesn't look neither Maven or WTP problem, as the project is being properly deployed.

Comment: nah, build automatically is enabled. I've have done no specific settings to either of the projects. Just installed the plugins listed above before importing the maven.pom and creating the dynamic web-project

Comment: I don't understand your concrete question/problem anymore. Publishing is exactly the step of copying changes from build folder to deploy folder. If you want to turn off publishing but still want to copy changes, you're basically contradicting yourself.

Comment: Sorry im likely using the wrong terminology. In the simpler project, saving a none-java-file results in the file being copied, but it avoids the timeconsuming task of re-deploying ejb:s. This is the behaviour I want. However in the maven project, saving a text-file results in all ejb:s being re-deployed also

Comment: That step is called "hot deployment". The server scans the deploy folder for changes and hotdeploys. This is usually to be configured in server end. But, to summarize your problem, the undesired redeployment of EJBs on save/publish of a Facelets file occurs only in a Maven flavored project and not in a standard dynamic web project?

Comment: Yep. And both are setup towards the same server, in the same fresh eclipse install, in the same fresh workspace

Comment: Apparently Maven is also touching `/WEB-INF/classes` or `/WEB-INF/lib` which would trigger hotdeployment of classes. This shouldn't happen if a simple Facelet file is changed. Perhaps Maven is overzealously building? Sorry, can't go more in detail as I don't do Maven.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally managed to solve this. This was the minimum amount of required steps i needed to do for a freshly created Maven project (which also had a dependency to another project in the workspace)

In eclipse Project properties > Maven uncheck "Resolve dependencies from workspace projects"

In The pom file set runOnIncremental for the goal: war for maven-war-plugin to false

```
<build>
    ...
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[1.0.0,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>war</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <execute>
                                        <runOnIncremental>false</runOnIncremental>
                                    </execute>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```